# AuthorizationPolicy by UserName was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-authorization

I'm trying to add a new policy based authorization for a certain user who needs to execute certain actions of a controller that requires rights. I'm new with Policy based authorization but I followed all the instructions on [this](https://www.codementor.io/jamierebello/how-to-implement-policy-based-authorization-using-asp-net-core-m2tw0uz5u) post, and seems pretty simple.

In my Startup.cs and after the **AddMvc()** method I have:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AgentsActivityReport ", policy => policy.RequireUserName("AnaR"));
});
```

Then, In my controller action I have:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AgentsActivityReport")]
public ActionResult AgentsActivity()
{
    //some code
}
```

However, when I launch the application, I receive the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The AuthorizationPolicy named:
>   'AgentsActivityReport' was not found.

I have also readed a few other threads/posts such as:

[Claim Based And Policy-Based Authorization With ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/claim-based-and-policy-based-authorization-with-asp-net-core-2-1/)

[reported issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1530)

And everything seems pretty much correct. Any thougts?

Comment: There may be an error in the configuration, but without seeing it it's hard to tell. It could be that the authorization is replaced by a later registration. Did you add 'AddAuthorization' twice or add other authorization features? Can you show the complete startup?

Comment: Hi Ruard, I have solved the issue by declaring a bit different my policy. I will post my answer in a while. However I appreciate your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://andrewlock.net/custom-authorisation-policies-and-requirements-in-asp-net-core/) post, I was able to declare and allow my user to invoke an action of a controller by using a requirement. Since my condition has to be, "allow certain roles OR a certain user named AnaR", I had to put that logic into the **AuthorizationHandler.cs**

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
         options.AddPolicy("ReportActivityPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.AddRequirements(new UserNameRequirement("AnaR"));                    
            });
        });

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AgentsActivityAuthorizationHandler>();
```

And then, in a separate file:

```
public class AgentsActivityAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserNameRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserNameRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.IsInRole("Administrator") || context.User.IsInRole("Manager") || context.User.Identity.Name == requirement.UserName)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}

public class UserNameRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public UserNameRequirement(string username)
    {
        this.UserName = username;
    }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in my controller, the following:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ReportActivityPolicy")]
public ActionResult AgentsActivity()
{
    //code of your controller.
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you register a policy named `"AgentsActivityReport "` with a white space at the end in the middleware but annotate the controller without the whitespace `"AgentsActivityReport"`.

Comment: I leave it as it is, because probably this was the problem. It's an old post, but it is good for the rest to check that they set the string correctly.